# Can't run python script on startup. Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: scripting, cron, python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a python script when my Raspberry pi 4 boots. THis python script works when I run it directly, with no errors. I have edited the crontab file to do this as can be seen below:

```
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot python /home/pi/FUZEGUI.py > /home/pi/FUZEGUIlog.txt
```

The log file has no information in it.
I have tried a different method, `rc.local`;

```
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
printf "Launching FUZE GUI"
sudo python home/pi/FUZEGUI.py &
exit 0
```

But that doesn't work either.
**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.geometry("800x800")

# Define Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)


# translates an rgb tuple of int to a tkinter friendly color code
def _from_rgb(rgb):
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb


# Called when user presses View Log button
def viewLogRaise():
    # Hide Previous Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(logButtonWindow, state="hidden")
    canvas.itemconfigure(titleLabelWindow, state="hidden")
    # Open Closed Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(backButtonWindow, state="normal")
    canvas.itemconfigure(logTextWindow, state="normal")
    canvas.itemconfigure(scrollbarWindow, state="normal")
    #I want to read the file continuously at this point.
    t =threading.Thread(target=readFile)
    t.start()

def backToMenu():
    # Hide Previous Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(backButtonWindow, state="hidden")
    canvas.itemconfigure(logTextWindow, state="hidden")
    canvas.itemconfigure(scrollbarWindow, state="hidden")
    # Open Closed Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(logButtonWindow, state="normal")
    canvas.itemconfigure(titleLabelWindow, state="normal")


def follow(thefile,reading):
    count= 0
    thefile.seek(0, 2)
    count += 1
    while reading == True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line
def readFile():
    logfile = open("fast.log", "r")
    loglines = follow(logfile,True)
    for line in loglines:
        logText.insert(tk.END, line)
    


# Background
pathToGif = "redpoly4.jpg"
# red_background=Image.open("redBackground.gif")
backgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=pathToGif)
canvas.background = backgroundImage
bg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=backgroundImage)
titleLabel = tk.Label(root, fg="white", text="FUZE", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)),
                      font=("Courier", 100))
titleLabelWindow = canvas.create_window(400, 120, window=titleLabel)
logButton = tk.Button(root, fg="white", text="View Log", command=viewLogRaise, borderwidth=2, relief="raised",
                      bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)), font=("Courier", 46))
logButtonWindow = canvas.create_window(400, 320, window=logButton)
backButton = tk.Button(root, fg="white", text="Back", command=backToMenu, borderwidth=2, relief="raised",
                       bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)), font=("Courier", 20))
backButtonWindow = canvas.create_window(70, 360, window=backButton)



canvas.itemconfigure(backButtonWindow, state="hidden")
logText = tk.Text(root, bg="white", height=22, width=60, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
logTextWindow = canvas.create_window(450, 208, window=logText)
# attach text widget to scrollbar
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=3)
scrollbarWindow = canvas.create_window(710,200, window=scrollbar)
logText.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=logText.yview)
canvas.itemconfigure(scrollbarWindow,state="hidden")
canvas.itemconfigure(logTextWindow, state="hidden")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you getting error mesages? If you start your computer only once a day, you should use anacron. It will check to see if the script has been run in the past n days. Does your Raspberry Pi use systemd? If so, you can just create a unit file for your script.

Comment: If you are running systemd, you might be able to access the cron logs through `journalctl -u cron.service`. 
Also look in the following places for any hints of failed jobs: `/var/log/cron`, `/var/log/syslog`, and `/var/log/messages`

Comment: @hakskel 
Jun 18 15:47:55 raspberrypi CRON[466]: (root) CMD (python /home/pi/FUZEGUI.py > /home/pi/FUZEGUIlog.txt)
Jun 18 15:47:56 raspberrypi CRON[414]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: @hakskel I found the error in one of the logs _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: Ok, this is because cron will spin up a new shell to run your script. Since this shell isn't attached to your display, there's nothing to output to. What you should do instead is create a shell script that will set the `DISPLAY` variable first. 
Open up a terminal on the Raspberry Pi (not while you're SSH'd into the device) and execute `echo $DISPLAY`. Most likely this will give you `:0`. Export this in your script before executing your python code: `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: echo $DISPLAY returns '0.0' so I put export DISPLAY=:0 above the @reboot python script.py in the crontab. This does not work. Should I make a bash script with the two line instead?

Comment: I think @hakskel comments miss the elephant in the room (correct phrase?). At boot time, there won't be any GUI running, so no $DISPLAY anywhere, doesn't matter which shell you start it from. @summertime got it right: you want to use `anacron`, which will run your script once daily some short time after you turn on the computer.

Comment: @q.undertow the script needs to be ran immediately on launch so the user does not see the desktop

Comment: What kind of desktop environment is in use? This sounds like something that should go into the desktop startup script line `~/.xsession` or `~/.config/openbox/autorun` or ... it's different for each environment, so we'll need to know which one it is.